# Logistic Regression in R with Categorical Predictors

Tags: r, logistic-regression

I have created a model for predicting sales achievement, however the results of the prediction are not close to real results.  All of the predictors are categorical so I am wondering if that is the issue?  Below is my code i am using.

```
setwd("c:/Users/xxxxx/Desktop/SalesPredict/")
trainData <- read.csv("train3.csv", header = TRUE)
testData <- read.csv("test3.csv", header = TRUE)
train.column.types <- c('character', # Prospect
                    'factor', # Sls_Office
                    'factor', # Month
                    'factor', # Sls_Rep
                    'factor', # Fin_Type
                    'factor', # Competitor
                    'integer', # Prospect_Size
                    'factor' , # Prospect_Segment
                    'factor' # Sold
)

test.column.types <- train.column.types[-9]

train.glm <- glm(Sold ~ Competitor + Prospect_Segment + Sls_Office + Month + Fin_Type  , family = binomial(link=logit), data = trainData)

summary(train.glm)

p.hats <- predict.glm(train.glm, newdata = testData, type = "response")

Sold <- vector()
for(i in 1:length(p.hats)) {
  if(p.hats[i] > .5) {
Sold[i] <- 1
 } else {
Sold[i] <- 0
 }
}

Enrolled_Segment = testData[8]
Month = testData[3]
Enrolled_EE = testData[7]
predict.sub <- cbind(Prospect_Segment, Sold, Month,Prospect_Size)
colnames(predict.sub) <- c("Segment","Predicted Disposition","Month","Size")
write.csv(predict.sub, file = "SalesPredictions.csv", row.names = FALSE)
```

Do i need to convert the categorical variables to something other?  The train data set has approximately 1650 rows - which are real actual results and the test (which i am trying to predict outcome of) has approximately 540 rows.  These 540 are real also, so i know what the approximate expected outcome should be.  In the train data, sold = 1 approximately 11% of the time.  In the test data, the prediction results in sold = "1" 0 times.  Any help or direction on how to improve this would be appreciated.

Comment: What are you using the `test.column.types` and `train.column.types` variables for?

Comment: This means the predicted probabilities for your logistic regression models are below 50% for all observations -- this is typical of logistic regression in an unbalanced dataset with many more negative than positive observations. You can see the distribution of the predicted probabilities with `hist(p.hats)`.

Comment: Thanks @josilber.  It was helpful to look st the histogram to see where the results fell.

Answer (score 1):

If your question is do I need to convert factor variables to something else when using `glm`, the answer is no. If the variable truly represents a categorical variable, keeping them as a factor is the correct thing to do. R by default will use reference level coding to perform the statistical analysis as requested.

If you are not getting the results you expect, the variable class is not the problem.As @josiber pointed out, it may simply be a shortcoming of logistic regression in the case of unbalanced data. However, since you did not produce enough data to make your example reproducible, it is hard to be absolutely certain of that.

Comment: Thanks @MrFlick.  Is there a way to balance the unbalanced train data (I presume the issue is with the train and not the test data).  I can provide sample data i am using if it would help.

Comment: @user3630656 You should always provide test data when you post a question anyway. Without actually being able to run code and see the output, it is very hard to debug. I'm guessing your training data just might not be that informative. Cutting on a p-hat value >.5 might be too high. You might want to plot an ROC type curve to see how you many "correct" answers you capture with different cut offs.

Comment: thanks.  i will post test data shortly.  Is there a lower limit where cutting off the pHat value is too low?  For example, if I cut it off at ~.15 the results are close to expected - but i was concerned that be going so low it was becoming unmeaningful.  Your thoughts are appreciated.

Comment: @user3630656 That's more of a statistical question than programming. I would consult a statistician who might know more about your data and can advise on better analysis methods.

Comment: See [this](http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/58756/compare-classifiers-based-on-auroc-or-accuracy/58761) & related questions on Cross Validated, as well as [Scoring rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scoring_rule) on Wikipedia. If you have costs for the two kinds of misclassification you can easily determine appropriate probability cut-offs; otherwise it's more sensible to use discrimination or calibration metrics to assess model performance.